# OnActionFromStart(Tapestry)

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm using this following java and tml code

java

```
    private void onActionFromStart(int id)
    {
       // here im getting url for the particular overlay when onclick 
    }
```

In tml

```
    <t:loop t:source="videos" t:value="pojo">

        <t:actionlink t:id="start" t:context="${pojo.id}" rel="#overlay1">
           // here image tag 
        </t:actionlink>
    </t:loop>
```

my problem is when i click on the image it get overlayed but onActionFromStart is not triggered how to solve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Action handlers need to have default or public modifiers for Tapestry to be able to find them:

```
void onActionFromStart(int id) {
    ...
}
```

Also take a look at the [Component Events](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-events.html) section of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you reload the server and refresh the page.

Action handlers should not be private.

Try:

`public void onActionFromStart(int id) {
    ...
}`

Or, using tapestry's anotations

```
    @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.ACTION, component = "start")
    public void start(int id){
    ...
    }
```